# Can I get DirectX(any version) to callback when logging an error?

Tags: c++, debugging, directx, callback

I have output like this after choosing debug version in the directx cpl:

```
Direct3D9: (WARN) :Ignoring redundant SetTextureStageState. Stage: 0, State: 3
Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Memory Address: 008307ec lAllocID=1 dwSize=00004bc4, ReturnAddr=7248d5ea (pid=000017d4)
```

Is it possible to define a callback which is triggered when these notifications are added to the console, like with keyboard/mouse input? I want to be able to do more based on the information.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible.  You CAN, however, set "Break on error", "Break on leaks" and break on a specific AllocID via the DirectX control panel.

I'm not sure there is a way to break on warnings mind ...

Edit: In the case of a redundant render state change as above these are pretty easy to fix.  Just make sure you remember what the pipeline is currently set to and only set if something has changed.  Thus the redundant warnings will disappear :)